# Internet Cable Has Been cut in two and taped back together

Tags: internet, layer1, cable, cabling, speed

Let me explain, we have a two analogue lines (something like 16 pair each, the standard cable that's put into buildings) that come into our building but they pass through the building next door.

These two cables were cut  in two places (and i mean straight through its now 3 cables), the engineers then twisted each individual cable back together and used insulation tape to keep it together.

What I want to know is what side effects should I be getting from the damaged cables.
I have been pinging an outside IP address all day in CMD and every 16 ping's or so I get 1-2 timeouts.

I hope this is the correct place to put this on stack exchange? if its not sorry :)

Comment: I don't even know where to start trying to answer... Just replace the cable. Physical plan (aka cables in this case) is simple and inexpensive (compared to the headaches it can cause.)

Comment: The cables That need replacing are the ones that our internet service provider would have put in.

Comment: Call the ISP and get the cable fixed.

Comment: I agree with Craig, if this is an ISP maintained cable, then I would insist that they do it right.  I don't know of a quality ISP that would operate this way.

Comment: The only problem I see is that the tape might not provide a trully hermetic seal against water and allow water to seep in. A good repair is to use a specific porpuse join and some 3M tape that I dont know the english name for it, but is made out of rubber and is self-sealing (maybe self-sealing tape ?).

Comment: No solder should be used, mechanical contact is better in those cases (you might verify that normal ethernet never uses solder in any place, everything is done by mechanical contact). This is to avoid galvanic corrosion induced by the contact between two different metals, the presence of water and electrical charges.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This can introduce a number of problems, like additional attenuation or cross talk.  Splicing is to be avoided whenever possible, but I have seen this work in a pinch although I would **never** recommend it.  They key is to use a cable certification tester (not just a continuity tester) to make sure it still passes your required standard (Cat5/5E/6) after splicing.

I would also be concerned about the manner of the splice.  Twisting and electrical tape are not a reliable splicing method.  Even if it is working properly initially, there is too much chance of problems to occur over time as the cables move slightly (temp changes, building vibrations, large vehicles driving by, etc).

The very first type of problem you can experience would be the inability to connect over the cable.  Since it appears you can do so, then the next problem would be frame loss, often from corrupted frames that will get dropped when they fail a consistency check.

If you have real equipment on both sides of this link, you should be able to view the interface statistics and see how many frames are being dropped as well as the reasons.